# Android unleavable activity

Tags: android, sms

I'm writing an anti theft app, and I want when sim card is changed a dialog opens on boot and tell the finder to bring back the phone. This activity must be unleavable, so he can't leave it unless the correct code is entered.

Other situation is when user send a lock SMS to the phone.

I know how a device admin can lock the phone, but lock don't tell the message and the password can't be entered. And lock may not have a password or pattern so the finder can pass it easily.

Maybe a combination of device lock and a full screen activity which disable the keyguard do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my research, without being installed at the OEM level, you can't make it 100% un-leavable, just really annoying.

In an app I wrote for businesses which use a kiosk, since we weren't at the OEM level, we just kept the menu bar hidden and set the app to be loaded whenever Home was hit.  Keeping the menu bar hidden was a pain, but was achieved by making it invisible and then when re-triggered, making it go away after 1 second.  It's still able to be exited by hitting the clock in that 1 second, though. :(